# Is there any text search tool preloaded with well-known regexes?

Tags: regular-expression, utilities

I would like to know if there is any command line tool to search text files preloaded with some well-known regexes (IP, email, date, path, url, xml tags, etc) so you could do something like:

```
grep -A 5 '443: open' somefile.log | getregexmatch --ip
```

To extract all the IP addresses from the output of `grep`.

Comment: What is the well-known regex for email?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I want to extract the IP without cut, AWK and other similar tools im using right now

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You are right, thank you.

Comment: Note that `IP` may not be a very good choice of an example here as there are so many ways to represent IP (IPv4 and IPv6) addresses. For instance, here, would that mean IPv4 addresses in quad-decimal (accepting leading 0s) notation or any standard representation of IPv4 or IPv6 IP addresses? Would it find a `0.0.0.0` IP address in `foo0.0.0.0bar` or `0.0.0.0.0` or `(0.0.0.0)`, or only as whole blank-separated words...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I think IP is a perfect example. I know there are a thousand ways to represent IP, as there are a thousand ways to represent an email (using IP instead of a domain for example), a date (hypens or slashes) or path (back slash, fordward slash, escaped slashes, ...) but I'm not looking for a comprehensive list of regexes to cover every corner case (I know how to write my own regex for that scenarios), just a simple tool to save myself some typing on regular cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, perl is your friend. In this case perl's Regexp::Common in particular. It provides predefined regex definitions (see the documentation for more details : http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common-2016020301/lib/Regexp/Common.pm).

An IPv4 example would be :

```
$ perl -MRegexp::Common -lne 'print $1 if /($RE{net}{IPv4})/g' file
172.18.0.1
172.17.0.1
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Probably better with `perl -MRegexp::Common -lne 'print for /$RE{net}{IPv4}/g'` to return all the matches.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas good point. Will correct the answer.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but probably the closest solution. Thank you both.